# mysql make a strong relationship with or without FK relationship

Tags: mysql, relationship

Table Name : Members (member_id PK), Member_Articles (articles_id PK)

I want to design, like below:

1. Member can write Articles, and there should be strong relationship. Without member_id, Member_Articles table can't insert any data.
2. Sometimes in the future, some member_id [e.g) member_id : 7] must be deleted. 
   However, some articles which are written by some member_id [e.g) member_id : 7] must remain in the table.

I tried PK, FK relationship. However, as you know, I had to delete first Articles before delete Member.

How can I implement this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While defining relationship set null on delete to the FK, and keep an extra column let say `deleted_member_id` and set it default with null if you delete the user programmatically or with the help of triggers set the `deleted_member_id` with the `memeber_id` and the delete will set null to `memeber_id`

**Better Approach** (in my view)

In my view the better approach could be setting flags into your eahc table,

For example: Create a column `status` with default `1` when you delete any data rather then of deleting them just set the `status` to 0, similarly in all your `SELECT` add an extra condition `WHERE status = 1`

Comment: I considered flag things, however Members table have lots of personal data, which is confidential. So, the member data must be deleted.

Comment: then what about those data you are not needed to delete for some reasons?

Comment: and, I also want Member_Articles tables FK member_id column don't accept Null.

Comment: you can keep the id with `deleted_member_id`

Comment: you mean ? ==> 
Members (member_id PK), Member_Articles( article_id PK, member_id FK (not null), deleted_member_id (null))..

Comment: yes and when you are deleting member. you will set deleted_member_id = <id> and delete the Members where member_id = <id>, it will set Member_Articles.member_id to null and delete the record from your Members

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Members` (
  `member_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `member_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Members_Articles` (
  `article_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Members_member_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `Member_deleted_member_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`),
  INDEX `fk_Members_Articles_Members_idx` (`Members_member_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Members_Articles_Members`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Members_member_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Members` (`member_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Comment: INSERT INTO `mydb`.`Members` (`member_name`) VALUES ('John');

INSERT INTO `mydb`.`Members_Articles` (`article_title`,`Members_member_id`,`Member_deleted_member_id`)
VALUES ('Great News',1,null);

select * from Members;
select * from Members_Articles;

delete from Members where member_id = 1;

select * from Members;
select * from Members_Articles;

Comment: Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`Members_Articles`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Members_Articles_Members` FOREIGN KEY (`Members_member_id`) REFERENCES `Members` (`member_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: I really appreciate your GREAT effort!! It works. Thank you again...
One more thing, is it possible Members_member_id INT NULL, ==> Members_member_id INT NOT NULL ?
Because, I really need "Strong" relationship.

Comment: relationship exists between two tables, if you dont have a row with specific value in [PK] table how could you keep a raw with that value in [FK] table and that was the only reason we keep `deleted_member_id`

Answer (score 0):

make member_id not null in your member_article table, and use on delete no action, to retain the articles.